# Mimicking NFC with iBeacon: plausible? appropriate?

Tags: android, ios, nfc, ibeacon

I'm creating an app in which a key piece is transferring data when two people press a button on the app on their respective devices and then press their phones together (Yes, Bump on Android does this. That isn't the point). I know I could use NFC on Android to get this done. However, I wouldn't be able to do this on iOS because iOS doesn't support NFC. Earlier today I read about and discovered iBeacon, which is apparently some Bluetooth 4.0 implementation that works with both iPhones and Android devices. I've read about retail use-cases of iBeacon, where stores could set up beacons and when users walk by or are close enough, it'll trigger an action. Is the use-case of mimicking NFC for my purposes to be able to do reach iPhone users plausible? Should I be using another solution? Is this not the purpose of iBeacon and it wouldn't work?

Comment: We're looking for developers familiar with BLE.  How have you progressed?

Comment: I know more about it and the many limitations it has.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience with iBeacon on Android, you can indeed use it to replace NFC, as there are 3 'ranges' (immediate, near and far). iBeacon is based off BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) and very light on power consumption as the name would suggest.

If you are trying to trigger actions on devices in a certain vicinity, i'd say using iBeacon is the most plausable method.

Android doesn't natively support 'iBeacon' as Apple created it, but it is based off Blueooth 4.0, a library has been created to mimick the iOS implementation of iBeacon

[Android iBeacon Library](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/)

One thing to note, is that when using iBeacons, you cannot transmit data. Only two numbers (a major, and minor) and a UUID used solely for identification purposes.

Comment: If you read the other answer, it seems that iBeacons are for transmission only to alert phones that the beacons are present. If my goal is to transmit user_ids, I might be able to sneak that into the transmission. Otherwise, it could be a bit cumbersome.

Comment: Yes you could pass user ids, by using the major and minor parts of the iBeacon identifier to encode the UserID. You could then use a web service to exchange data. If you have more users than available major and minor combinations then you could connect to the web service when the button is clicked to lease a id for a short period whilst the connection is made.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with using iBeacons for this is that iBeacons are transmit only devices designed only to alert phones to their presence.  The technology cannot exchange data.

You could do something like you describe with low-level programming with Bluetooth LE technologies, but iBeacons alone cannot do the job.

Comment: Ah, yes, I just stumbled across that information. I'm curious, because it seems that iBeacons transmit 3 small bits of data for identification purpose. If my goal is to only transmit a user_id, then I wonder if I could sneak that into the transmission.

Comment: That would depend on the type of device that's acting as a beacon. If it's another iOS device that's acting as the beacon, then yes, you could transmit the user_id too. However, most beacons are single-purpose devices, like the Estimote beacons, which are going to have no knowledge of your system or the users of that system.

Comment: The only devices that would act as beacons are iOS devices and Android devices. So users would be people on their iPhones and people on the Android phones. If I could transmit the user_id, then I'm all set.

Comment: Yes, you can encode any data you want into the iBeacon transmission.  For iOS receivers, you can only use a two byte "major" field and a two byte "minor" field.  With Android receivers, you can also use a 16-byte UUID to encode data.  You cannot use this field for encoding with iOS receivers because iOS can only detect iBeacons if told the UUID up front.